# Why does U sound like W in words like "penguin"?

Tags: orthography, pronunciation-vs-spelling, language-evolution, phonetics

A semivowel is a vowel that acts like a consonant (including only W and Y and yet U sounds like W sound in words such as *penguin*, *sanguine*, but not in *guide*. Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: In the case of *sanguine*, the word is clearly of Norman french origin, but the French certainly don't pronounce a W sound. (The W rarely exists in French) But a W was used in its English spelling until the sixteenth century. *Penguin* is believed to be of Welsh origin - *pen gwyn*. (*pen*, "head" and *gwyn*, "white", a name first given to the Great Auk, which the Penguin resembles but to which it is unrelated.) But none of this explains why the W has been dropped!

Comment: It isn't that U sounds like W it's just the natural transition the lips make going from the /uː/ sound to the /ɪ/ sound.  *Guide* doesn't do it because the *ui* in *guide* is not pronounced /uːɪ/.  Try it yourself: say "goo-in" making sure not to deliberately say "gwin". It's there anyway.

Comment: @WS2 French don't have a W sound? oi ?

Comment: @Jim Nice theory, but it doesn't sound like it can be the full story. Consider *doing* /du:ɪŋ / which we don't pronounce "dwing"!

Comment: @SrJoven I think WS2 is mixing up sound and letter. The letter ‹w› is indeed quite rare in French—and when it does show up, it usually represents [v] in speech (except in recent English loan words like _un show_). The sound [w] is quite common, though, being the non-syllabic allophone of /u/, written ‹ou› (or ‹oi› for the diphthong [wa] when it comes historically from /eː/).

Comment: @SrJoven My apologies. I could have worded my comment better. It is the letter W that is rare in French, and when they say it they call it *dou-ble-vey*. But *mais oui* of course they is a W sound.

Comment: @Araucaria But how do you not pronounce doing like doo wing? or going go wing?

Comment: @SrJoven Well, we could, although most people actually don't, insert a glide in those two words. However that's my point really - we don't say *Peng **goo** win* - there's no /u:/ in there in the first place! We *might* get [du:wɪŋ] we difinitely don't have [dwɪŋ]! Do we?

Answer (score 6):

You've got things backward in your question. Orthographic <u> doesn't ‘sound’ like anything at all: it's a letter, not a sound. Writing is an attempt (both syn- and diachronic) to represent the sounds and patterns of spoken language on paper. Different people speaking different languages have approached this task in different ways throughout the ages.

In Latin, for example, lowercase <u> and uppercase <V> were not distinguished: they both represent the vowel /u/ and the glide /w/, since the two represent one phoneme. Words like *sanguine* have been borrowed directly from mediaeval Latin (as used and spoken by the Old French, but different from the Old French vernacular) into English, along with an approximated pronunciation (which has since changed somewhat in English). The spelling is basically kept intact, though, rather than being transformed into **sangwine* or something like that.

A word like *guide* is ultimately Latin in origin, but English borrowed it from the Old French vernacular, where some sound changes had already happened—for one, the /w/ glide had disappeared, though the spelling had not been changed. So here there never was a glide /w/ in the word (from the English perspective), but again the spelling in the language the word was borrowed from was maintained.

As Henry said, *penguin* is a Welsh word in origin, *pen gwyn* ‘white head’. This is a later word than the other two, and at the time, it was apparently felt that <gw> looked ‘un-English’ somehow due to the paucity of other words using this combination to represent /gw/. The only places where <gw> really appears in English is across morpheme boundaries, like in *longwinded*. So when the Welsh was borrowed into English, the spelling was not kept intact, but adapted to look more English. This often happens when the source language is not a ‘classical’ one (Greek or Latin and its descendants). Thus, the glide /w/ in *penguin* was represented with the more ‘normal-looking’ <gu>.

In other words, the presence of a <u> in a word like one of these can either just be a historical coincidence (maintaining a way of spelling something in a different language even though it has no clear connection to anything in the word as it is borrowed into English), or it can be an attempt to actually represent the glide /w/ in the word as it is pronounced in English. As always in English, you must know both how to pronounce and how to write the word—you can't guess one from the other.

Answer (score 2):

*penguin* comes from a name for the Great Auk in the north Atlantic, and is thought to be Welsh *pen + gwyn* (head + white).  Drake then switched it to the south Atlantic in 1578.

Both *sanguine* and *guide* come from French and do not have this difference there, though those with a classical education or who attended Latin mass would have known of the Latin *sanguis* or *sanguineus* where the *u* does involve a semi-vowel.

Comment: Regardless of linguistic origin, the spelling was likely changed to match qu/gu words.  And "guide" likely changed due to the Great Vowel Shift.